# Java - parsing source code - illegal argument exception

Tags: java, html, parsing

I parsed source code from yahoo finance and I had no problem in reading the data. I used this static method:

```
public static String readYahooHtml(String symbol) {
    In page = new In("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + symbol);
    String html = page.readAll();
    if (html.contains("<title></title>")) return null;
    else return html;
}
```

Page example https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AES

When I try to do the same to a source code from gurufocus

```
    // Given symbol, get HTML
public static String readGuruFocusHtml(String symbol) {
    In page = new In("http://www.gurufocus.com/stock/" + symbol);
    String htmlGF = page.readAll();
    if (htmlGF.contains("<title></title>")) return null;
    else return htmlGF;
}
```

I get the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not open http://www.gurufocus.com/

Page example - http://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AES

Why is that so? Maybe the source type is a bit different or something like that ? Is there any way to block the access to a source code ?

Edit: There's no need to debug the code, it's here just so you can see that this code works.

The entire stacktace:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not open http://www.gurufocus.com/
    at Algorithms.Tools.In.(In.java:186)
    at Investing.TestData.main(TestData.java:16)

Comment: So, what do you expect from us? That we spend our time debugging why one of the two sites **you** are interested in gives you an error? Sorry, but this is not a **debugging** service.

Comment: @GhostCat No. It's not a debugging question. Maybe the access to the source code  is restriced (some data on this site is for members, though not this data)

Comment: @GhostCat I expect people here to answer what can cause this problem - Different type of file/ letting me know if there's an option to block data streaming of source code. There's no need to check the code.

Comment: If you post your stacktrace in the question, I figure there’s a chance someone will be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @OleV.V. - it's there.

Comment: I see the exception. I don’t see the stcktrace. What I was after was which class the exception comes from. Whether it’s your class or some 3rd party code. PS I can open http://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AES in my browser, so at first glance it seems the URL is correct.

Comment: @OleV.V. This code works with other source code, so everything should be fine. There's no problem with In class.

Comment: Again: a single line is **not** a stacktrace. Do you want us to help you - if so, provide the information we ask for. If **there is no problem in class** then why are things failing?

Comment: Next time, use DEBUG. Connection to your URL returning 403, difference between Java and browser is what? Empty request properties! Webserver can be configured to dont allow these kinds of request. Solution for you is in my answer.

Comment: @Hrabosch, thanks! I didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that it returning you 403 ;)
You can try to add request property to your connection. But I don't know where you are opening it, maybe in `In` object?

Something like this:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://www.gurufocus.com/stock/" + symbol).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
connection.connect();
```

Ok, I tried it and with this request property it is OK, so complete code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
      URL page = null;
      try {
        page = new URL("http://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AES");
        URLConnection connection = page.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
          a.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        System.out.println(a.toString());


      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Just to complete answer, [here](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/block-bots-with-htaccess.shtml) is good article about webserver security and how to block Bots. In this case, you calling was Bot ;)

Comment: Yes,it's in In class. It's third part. It worked well when I tried to get data from yahoo finance.

Comment: Then, you have to add header to your reqeust. Is it possible to add to `In`?

Comment: Something like `page.setRequestProperty` ?

Comment: Your solution is similar to what I wrote for getting data from a csv file, maybe I should have done the same, rather than using a third party class.

Comment: Maybe, try it. But main point is that webserver can be configured to don't allow request without Agent-Type, then you get 403 (difference between yahoo and gurufocus) so you have to set valid headers to your request.

Comment: "webserver can be configured to don't allow request without Agent-Type then you get 403" - I looked for that kind of answer, thanks!  The Agent-Type is the java's agent that tries to connect with the webserver or what ? ( I'm not familiar that much with data streaming from the internet)